# In python 3.7 is it possible to take an integer input and have it assigned a different numeric value?

Tags: python, integer, mapping

I am new to python and am currently trying to write a program that determines the distance between two numbers on a roulette wheel. For example, on the wheel, the number 21 is 3 spaces to the right of 15. I want to be able to type in any two numbers and have the program tell me how far apart they are or how many spaces the second number is to the right of the first number.

My approach is to assign each number on the wheel starting at zero and moving clockwise a value between 1 and 37 and use simple subtraction to determine how far apart they are. Basically, I want to take an integer input between 0 and 36 and have it assigned a different numeric value between 1 and 37. In other words, how can I make it so that if I type in the number 21 for example that the program reads it as the number 6?

This is what I have so far:

```
    import math
    
    def subtract(x, y):
        return x - y
    
    print("Use this program to determine the distance between two roulette numbers")
        
    while True:
        
        num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
        
        print(num2, "is", subtract(num1, num2), "spaces to the right of", num1)
        
        next_calculation = input("Input next pair? (yes/no): ")
        
        if next_calculation == "no":
              break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. I have **absolutely no idea** how you intend for this to work, or what you actually want to happen when you run the code. "In other words, how can I make it so that if I type in the number 21 for example that the program reads it as the number 6?" - *Why should the result be 6?* What is the rule that tells you that?

Comment: As an aside, you don't have to `import math` to do arithmetic. You *only* need it for the functions provided in the `math` standard library module. Just like with any other `import`.

Comment: You could hardcode a list ```distances = [] ``` with 37 ints in which the index of an item will be the roulette number and the value will be the distance from 0. So then in subtract you will do something like ```distances[x] - distances[y] ```.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I intend to label each number on the wheel starting at the green zero in the order [0, 1] [32, 2] [15, 3] [19, 4] [4, 5] [21, 6]. So if I type in 15 and 21 I would just have to do the operation 6-3 to know that it is 3 spaces to the right. I don't even know if this sort of program is possible it is more of an experimental project.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write the indices into the list yourself - I think what you are looking for is the `list.index()` method (https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index).

If you define your list as:

```
NUMBERS = [0, 32, 15, 19, 4, 21]
```

Then `NUMBERS.index(21)` evaluates to `6` and `NUMBERS.index(15)` evaluates to `3`.

Your `subtract` method above might look something like:

```
def subtract(x, y):
    return NUMBERS.index(x) - NUMBERS.index(y)
```

Note that `NUMBERS` would need to be defined globally in this case for the function to be able to access it.